# Replace "man" by "?"

Tags: linux, bash, unix, alias, manpage

I am using R a lot. In R, you can call a man page for a function by writing

```
?print
```

I got used to that so much that I intermittently type that in a bash shell window as well. Now, I have set up an alias

```
?='man'
```

that *almost* cuts it: I can do, for example, `? ls`. However, I would prefer it to work with `?ls`. Unfortunately, this one does not work. Is there any way to make bash call the man page when I type the question mark without the space after?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a way to do this since bash uses spaces to split up command line arguments: if you typed `?ls` (with `?` being the command and `ls` being the argument) bash wouldn't be able to tell what the command was: it could be `?`, or `?l`, or `?ls`, with the arguments being `ls`, `s`, or ` ` respectively.

Comment: I was thinking more in the direction of command prompt executables.

Comment: That's the problem: bash doesn't know whether `ls` should be considered a command prompt executable until it sees that the command is `man` (or `?`). And it doesn't know that until it sees a space after the command.

Comment: People should really learn to leave a comment when they downvote. This is a perfectly good programming question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bash` provides a hook for handling undefined commands. Since you are unlikely to ever have any commands whose names start with `?`, you can use this hook to process any attempt to run such a command:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ $1 =~ ^\? ]]; then
        cmd=${1#\?}
        man $cmd
    else
        echo "$1: command not found" >&2
        return 127
    fi
}
```

This function would go into your `.bashrc` file, so that is it available in any shell. When you try to execute

```
$ ?ls
```

the command is not found, the hook intercepts the failed attempt to find the command, determines that the command name starts with `?`, then strips the `?` and passes the result as an argument to `man`. Other undefined commands merely produce an error message similar to the default `bash` error for unfound commands and exits with status 127 (the same status `bash` usually uses to denote command not found).

Comment: This is wicked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Be careful, though, `?` has a special meaning in bash. Try `touch cls ; ?ls`.

Comment: @choroba: Very good point. I'm not sure there's any way around that aside from disabling pattern expansion with `set -f`. But if you find a situation where `?whatever` matches a file in the current directory, you can try again with `\?whatever`. The matched file shouldn't run as long as '.' isn't in your `PATH` (which it shouldn't be, for security reasons).